# Open modal from a different web page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm new in javascript and html5. I want to know if it is possible to open a modal (still in the form of modal) in page 1 which is defined in page 2 (not display page 2 in a modal of page 1). According to a senior developer, the best practice would be by using div overlay. Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: If you have service for page you want to show in modal, i say yes it is possible

Comment: Are you using **angularjs** framework? If yes, you can use **angular ui-modal**. It's an **angular directive** that can be use multiple times.